# Function to check if a given number do contain les than two different digits

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a function to check if a given number do contain les than two different digits, that are called duodigits

For example :

12 , 110 , -33333 : are all duodigits , since they have no more than two different digits
102 : is not a duodigit since his digits ; 1 and 0 and 2 are three different digits

How may I implement a method , which may iterate and check if it's a duodgits or not and return true or false as result

Comment: Make a `Set` whose elements are all the digits in the number. Then get the size of the set.

Comment: `new Set(Math.abs(num).toString().split("")).length > 2`

Comment: @2pichar A `Set` doesn’t have a `length`. You mean `size`.

Comment: @2pichar, note that you don't need the `split` because JS already considers strings to be arrays of characters ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
/**
 * Checks if a number is a duodigit.
 * @param {number} num 
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isDuodigit(num) {
  return new Set(Math.abs(num).toString()).size <= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution would be:

```js
function isDuoDigit(num) {

  const numArr = Array.from(num.toString());

  const uniqueNums = numArr.filter((num, index) => numArr.indexOf(num) === index);

  return uniqueNums.length > 2 ? "Number is not DuoDigit" : "Number is DuoDigit!"
}

console.log(isDuoDigit(11111000000)); // Number is DuoDigit!
console.log(isDuoDigit(111155555500000)); // Number is NOT DuoDigit!
```

1. Convert a number to an array of strings ( 102 = ["1", "0", "2"] )

   const numArr = Array.from(num.toString());
2. Get an array with unique values (without duplicates)

   const uniqueNums = numArr.filter((num, index) => numArr.indexOf(num) === index);
3. We check if length of uniqueNums array is more then 2. If it's true, it means number is NOT DuoDigit and if length of array 2 or less, number is DuoDigit

   return uniqueNums.length > 2 ? "Number is not DuoDigit" : "Number is DuoDigit!"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without a set or string conversion.

```
function isDuoDigit(num){
    num = Math.abs(num);
    let first = '', second = '';
      while (num > 0) {
        let digit = num % 10;
        if(first === '')
          first = digit
        else if(second === '')
          second = digit
        else if(first !== digit && second !== digit)
           return false;
        num = Math.trunc(num / 10);
      }
  return true;
}
```